# Why is it "untenable" and not "untainable" in English?

Tags: english, etymology

I am aware that words like "obtain," "retain," and "contain" are related to the root "tenere" meaning "to have."

What (if anything) determines if the "ten" goes to "tain" in English? We have words like:

1. Detention
2. Untenable
3. Tenacious
4. Tender

While also having words like

1. Unobtainable
2. Detain
3. Entertainment

I am aware of some words in Latin ending in "-tenire" instead of "-tenere" and I wonder if this is related?

Comment: -e- is the original spelling, so the question should really be why some forms have -ai-.  Small note on this at https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/maintenance

Comment: It looks as if you have isolated two different phases of development. Bittlingmayer's link does not explain why the spelling was changed, but I'd assume that it was to make the spelling phonetic. My first instinct is to assume Germanic heritage, and indeed there's a tangent (tan-g-ent :D) to *tooth*, if we may analoguously compare *fangs* and Ger *fangen* "to catch" and then some, but I haven't worked it out; I see no *zent-* in German, and assuming a late dental infix leads to mentioned *tooth*, which is, alas, corresponds to Latin *dent*. So it's coincidence … if one believes in coincidences

Comment: Much rather, it might just be a contrast of loans from Latinate French and Latin directly, respectively.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about @vectory in bringing in _teeth_ and _fangen_. I certainly thought that the difference was Latin vs French.

Comment: @ColinFine I don't know what you mean. Are you criticizing my english, my writing style or the stretched analogies and tentative comparisons? I was attempting to find Eng *ten-* < PGem ? > Ger *zent*. I made a mistake with *zent-*, ignoring the remaining T, obviously. The underlying call to action is for someone knowledgable to consider whether an Old English word form *ten-* could have been subsumed under the Latin form. I might add there's G *zieh'n* "to draw, pull", *Zug* "pull, draft", En *take* and *toke*; there's *Zange* "tongues, pliers"; and *Zehnt* "taxes; tenth". But no OE *ten-*?

Comment: To the close-voters: this certainly doesn't seem to be a grammar and usage question, it's a question about historical sound changes affecting a loanword.

Comment: @Draconis it really seems like this site is more and more being taken over by people who are really intent on closing a lot of questions with that particular reason, especially when it doesn't apply at all (it may have started with the "serial Slavic/Bible question asker"). Is there anything we can do about it beyond, well, this? One more vote, and this is already closed.

Comment: @LjL If it's closed, we can vote to reopen; in the meantime, I've brought it up on Meta before.

Comment: see, for instance, page 91 in Upward and Davidson *The history of English spelling* https://doi.org/10.1002/9781444342994.ch5

Answer (score 3):

#### Syllable codas in Old/Middle French, plus analogy.

In the development of French, Latin `/e/` developed differently in open syllables vs closed syllables: this is why we have "detain" (MFr *dé.t**e**.nir*) vs "detention" (MFr *dé.t**e**n.tion*).

The form in "detain" was usually spelled *ei* or *ey* in Middle English, separate from the vowel spelled *ai* or *ay* (which, in French, developed from Latin `/a/` in open syllables). The two were *probably* something like `[ej aj]` respectively, though of course we can't be too certain about pronunciation.

But over the lifetime of Middle English, those two diphthongs merged together, and their spellings varied wildly as people were no longer sure which ones to spell with an *e* and which ones to spell with an *a*. Eventually, "detain" and its brethren ended up spelled with *ai*, even though that vowel comes from a Latin *e* instead of a Latin *a*.

(Forms like "entertainment", with *ai* in a closed syllable, were either formed within English, or their spellings were changed by analogy with "entertain" and "entertaining".)